# Making WordPress development cycle and environment as smooth as Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress

I'm used to the smooth development cycle that Rails and the standard routines that have grown up around it, but lately I am finding myself more and more in WordPress development.  At best it seems clunky and disjointed.

There are a boatload of "best practices" floating around, but nothing seems quite cohesive and solid enough to make me feel at home so far.

Can you share what has worked for you to make the WP development cycle really gel together and work as someone might hope for when coming from a Unix based Rails / Git / Hg environment?  I don't care about the tools specifically so much as the actual workflow and how to set it up so that individuals and teams can work together more fluidly.

Comment: It's really funny that this question has gotten so many positive votes and two favorites so far, yet there are 4 votes to close this question. I certainly think we can see a clear incongruity here. This is really a great model question that begs to be answered by someone with experience, yet it seems it will likely be closed. How sad it is when the system neither receives such needed questions nor introspection.

Comment: While the disparity of votes vs being closed might seem odd, you have to remember the scope of StackOverflow is not discussions about best-practices. If you read why the question was closed, it failed to meet the guidelines for a constructive question as set up by the site's creators, and as voted on by your peers. Perhaps you can change the scope of your question and ask it differently, but remember, unless it's closely tied to a single programming question it will likely be closed again.

Comment: That is the thing though, sometimes you have to start with a generality in order to get down to the specifics.  Interaction leads to this.  The problem with this one, as evidenced by the votes and favorites is that people don't know precisely what to ask here.  People *do* want the answer, but aren't quite sure how to get there given the context.  That is where the failing comes in here with the erroneous judgement call by those who have dictated this kind of standard.

Comment: Those who "dictated" it, are the ones who created the site. I'd say it's their call since it's their dime. Instead of Stack Overflow, why didn't you ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ since their FAQ specifically says that site is for "development and management best practices"?

Comment: As a developer and business owner, I certainly appreciate input and like to be aware of what my customers think and want.  I think any good business traditionally feels the same, although we certainly see a dearth of that nowadays.  Sadly I won't get the input I wanted from Ruby / Rails developers on the WordPress stack, so it's not as good of a match.